# Convert genotypes to 0/1

Tags: text-processing, awk, replace

I have a file that looks like:

```
1    rs6687776    1020428    T    C    T    C    T    C    C    C    T    C    C    C    T    C
```

The 4th and 5th column are the two different possible [alleles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allele) at that site. I need to change column 6 onwards so as to show `0` if there is a `T` allele and `1` if there is a `C` allele. My file is 20805 x 459. So should look like:

```
1   rs6687776   1020428 T   C   0   1   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   1
```

I've tried:

```
cat file | while read line
do if [ [,6-] = [,4] ]
then
    echo "0"
    echo "1"
fi
done
```

But I just end up with a file of alternating `0`'s and `1`'s that is 41610 rows long. Maybe [AWK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) is more useful?

Comment: You seem to be saying that, in columns 6-459, you want to change `T` to `0` and `C` to `1`. Is that the issue? Do columns 4 and 5 have anything to do with the question?

Comment: yes so each row will have a different set of alleles, row 1 is T and C but the next row might be G and A and the next C and A.

Comment: You're not answering my question. If the 4th and 5th columns are `G` and `A`, do you still want to change `T` to `0` and `C` to `1` in columns 6-459?

Comment: if the letter in the 4th column matches the letter in columns 6-459 then replace the letter with 0 if it doesn't then replace it with 1. So yes, the 4th column has everything to do with the question

Comment: So, you're saying that, in columns 6-459, any column that matches the 4th column should be changed to `0`, and any column that *doesn't* match the 4th column should be changed to `1`? And the 5th column doesn't really matter? Warning: none of the three answers that you have received so far understand that the content of the 4th column has anything to do with what you want to happen to the rest of the line. Please [edit] your question to clarify it.

Comment: @G-Man the OP's file describes genetic polymorphisms. Each line shows the two different nucleotides that can be found at position N. So, for each line, we have two possible values, that of field4 or that of field5. The OP wants to change all cases of field4 to 0 and all cases of field5 to 1 but only for fields 6-last. Presumably, fields 6-last will always have either the value of field4 or that of field5.

Comment: @terdon: Well, thanks for interpreting, but, quite frankly, I’m not very interested in learning much biology today.  I want to get the OP to explain the problem in precise, general, *text-processing* terms, rather than hand-wavy, one-off, biology terms — which he/she *still* hasn’t done.  By caveating your last last sentence with “Presumably”, you’re proving my point.

Comment: @G-Man I know, I would also like the OP to do so. Since the question is kind of clear to me though, I thought I'd help explain it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's another `awk` approach:

```
$ awk '{a[$4]=0;a[$5]=1; for(i=6;i<=NF;i++){$i=a[$i]}}1;' file
1 rs6687776 1020428 T C 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1
```

#### Explanation

- `a[$4]=0;a[$5]=1;` : creates the array `a` with two keys, `$4` and `$5`. The value for `$4` is set to `0` and that of `$5` to 1.
- `for(i=6;i<=NF;i++){$i=a[$i]}` : for each field number from 6 to the last one, set that field to whatever is stored in the array for the nucleotide found.
- `1;` : awk shorthand for "print this line".

---

You could also do it with Perl:

```
$ perl -lane 's/$F[3]/0/ for @F[5..$#F]; s/$F[4]/1/ for @F[5..$#F]; print "@F"' file
1 rs6687776 1020428 T C 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1
```

This is the same idea. The `-a` makes `perl` act like `awk`, splitting each line on whitespace into the array `@F`. We then substitute all cases of the nucleotide found in the 4th field (`$F[3]`, arrays start at 0) with `0` and all cases of the 5th (`$F[4]`) with `1`. The `for  @F[5..$#F]` means that the substitution is only applied for fields 6 to last. Finally, the modified array is printed.

Comment: I trust you realize that your two answers are not equivalent in an error-handling sense.  Given an (invalid) input of `do re mi T C T T T CAT G G G C`, your `awk` solution produces `do re mi T C 0 0 0     1`, while your `perl` solution produces `do re mi T C 0 0 0 1A0 G G G 1`.  I’m not criticizing you (although IMO it would have been nice if you had highlighted the difference).  I’m pointing out that we only barely know that that input is invalid, because the OP was so reluctant to state the problem and the assumptions/background, and to characterize the input, *in **text-processing** terms*.

Comment: … and it goes without saying that we don’t have a clue what the OP want to have happen when the input doesn’t satisfy the imprecisely-stated assumptions.

Answer (score 3):

You can try following `awk`:

```
awk '{ for (i = 6; i <= NF; i++) { if ($i == $4) { $i = 0; } else if ($i == $5) { $i = 1; } } } 1' file
```

or:

```
awk '{ for (i = 6; i <= NF; i++) { $i = ($i == $4) ? 0 : 1; } } 1' file
```

Answer (score 2):

There's always more than one way to do it; sed is the Unix Stream EDitor -- it's useful for modifying input like this:

```
while read one two three four five rest
do
  echo $one $two $three $four $five $(echo $rest | sed -e 's/T/0/g' -e 's/C/1/g')
done < input
```

The -e flag gives it an expression to parse; the "s" function searches and replaces the first parameter (T or C) with the second parameter (0 or 1). You can give sed multiple expressions to do multiple things. The rest of the loop just preserves the first five fields.

Comment: This will work for the example shown but, for a file with 20805 lines, it will be very, very slow. It also only works for `T` and `C`. The values of the 4th and 5th field will be different on different lines.

Comment: then you can adapt the sed with something like `sed -e 's/${four}/0/g' -e 's/${five}/1/g'`. Also instead of sed you can use tr like in `$(echo $rest| tr [$four$five] [01])`